# Tweening a filter in an array not happening as expected

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I have this array of MovieClips (btnArr) and array of GlowFilters (gloArr):

```
var btnArr:Array = new Array(aBtn, bBtn, cBtn);
var gloArr:Array = new Array();
var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0x00aaff, 0,
                                     12, 12,
                                     5, 1,
                                     false, false);
for (var i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
        gloArr[btnArr[i].name] = glow;
        btnArr[i].filters = [gloArr[btnArr[i].name]];
}
```

However, when I, later in my code, Tween one of the GlowFilters in the array, it seems to apply the Tween to all of them.

```
var btnTween:Tween = new Tween(gloArr[e.currentTarget.name], "alpha",
                               Strong.easeIn,
                               gloArr[e.currentTarget.name].alpha, 1, 1, true);
trace(gloArr.indexOf(btnTween.obj));
```

I have traces set up which seem to show that until I declare that Tween all is going as expected, but the last trace there shows -1, and when I check the values of each individual filter in the array they are all increasing and decreasing together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a understood you correctly you only want to tween the glow of one of the buttons, right?

If that's the case you need to create separate instances of the `glow` object each time you assign it to `btnArr[i].filters = [glow]`. In your code you use only one instance of GlowFilter and share it for all of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks very much! You're absolutely right, having instantiated an unnamed filter for each position in the `gloArr` it now works absolutely perfectly. Thanks again.